# Must the norm of a character be an integer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, characters

I am working on a problem and I was very tempted to take for granted that for any complex character $\chi$ of a finite group $G$, the norm
$$\langle \chi, \chi \rangle = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} \chi(g)\chi( g^{-1})$$
Is an integer. I have pondered this for awhile and I don't see a reason why it is necessarily true, but nontheless I have never seen any inner product of characters be anything but an integer.

My initial thought was that any character is the integral sum of irreducible characters, so the norm will be a sum of square integers, but that isn't sufficient

Am I missing something obvious here? If this is not true, can someone provide an explicit example for my repertoire of examples?

Comment: @Timkinsella by complex character I mean the class function given by the trace of a representation $\rho: G \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{C})$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $G$ be finite, and restrict our attention to $G$-representations of finite degree over $\Bbb C$.

As you observe, to a $G$-representation $V$ we have a decomposition:
$$V\cong V_1^{d_1}\oplus \dots \oplus V_h^{d_h},$$
where the $V_i$ are the irreducible representations corresponding to the irreduciblecharacters $\chi_i$ of $G$, i.e. the character $\chi$ of $V$ is $d_1\chi_1+\dots + d_h\chi_h$, and the orthogonality condition on the irreducible characters implies that $$(\chi|\chi) = \sum_{i,j=1}^h (d_i\chi_i|d_j\chi_j) = \sum_{i=1}^h (d_i\chi_i|d_i\chi_i)=\sum_{i=1}^h d_i^2(\chi_i|\chi_i) = \sum_{i=1}^h d_i^2,$$
which is, as you say, a sum of integers, and hence an integer. I am not sure why you say this is insufficient.

Comment: I am concerned about the factor of 1/|G|, which you have not addressed here.

Comment: @VanishingPhilosopher Do you already know that $(\chi_i|\chi_j) = \delta_{ij}$ for $\chi_i$ irreducible $\Bbb C$-characters?

Comment: Ahh, I see. So the factor of 1/|G| is brought in to the inner product and thus goes away with the orthonormal inner products. That was what I missed, thank you